# Must Declare Scalar Variable?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Ok I'm having a hard time with this one, I've spent a couple days with google etc trying to figure out where I'm screwing up.

I'm extremely new to C# and what I'm doing is trying to grab the `Customer_ID (Primary Key)` From my SQL Server, add 1 to the value, then enter that as the next customer id.  If i Take out the part that adds the value to the `Customer_ID` field i get an error saying I can't insert a null value.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error is:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@custID".

Here is my code:

```
string firstName = fName.Text;
string lastName = lName.Text;
string address1 = address.Text;
string city = addressCity.Text;
string state = addressState.Text;
string zip1 = addressZip.Text;
string phoneNum = phone.Text;
string emailadd = custEmail.Text;
int finalCustID = 0;

SqlCommand getMaxCustID = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Customer_ID) FROM dbo.Customers", Form1.sqlConnection);
getMaxCustID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", finalCustID);
Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(getMaxCustID.ExecuteScalar());
finalCustID = (int)count + 1;
//Int32 newCustID = count + 1;

SqlCommand saveRecord = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Customers (Customer_ID,First_Name, Last_Name, Customer_Address,City,St,Zip,Phone,Email)" + "Values (@custID'firstName','lastName','address1','city','state','zip1','phoneNum','emailadd')", Form1.sqlConnection);

Console.Write(" This is the final ID " + finalCustID + " \n");
try
{
    saveRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.Write(saveRecord);
}
```

Here is what I ended up with.  I don't think it's the best but it's working properly.  Thanks all for the help:

```
        string firstName = fName.Text;
        string lastName = lName.Text;
        string address1 = address.Text;
        string city = addressCity.Text;
        string state = addressState.Text;
        string zip1 = addressZip.Text;
        string phoneNum = phone.Text;
        string emailadd = custEmail.Text;
        int finalCustID = 0;

        SqlCommand getMaxCustID = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Customer_ID) FROM dbo.Customers", Form1.sqlConnection);
        //getMaxCustID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", finalCustID);
        Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(getMaxCustID.ExecuteScalar());
        finalCustID = (int)count + 1;
        //Int32 newCustID = count + 1;

        SqlCommand saveRecord = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Customers " + "(Customer_ID,First_Name, Last_Name, Customer_Address,City,St,Zip,Phone,Email)" + " Values (@custID,@fName,@lName,@address,@city,@state," + "@zip,@phoneNumber,@custEmail)", Form1.sqlConnection); ;
        Console.Write(" This is the final ID " + finalCustID + " \n");
        try
        {
            saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", finalCustID);
            saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", firstName);
            saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", lastName);
            saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address1);
            saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city);
            saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", city);
            saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", zip1);
            saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneNumber", phoneNum);
            saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custEmail", emailadd);

            saveRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.Write(saveRecord);
        }
```

Comment: @Steve I assume you meant to say that this is NOT a good method. I would agree with that 100%. 

josh - The problem with this type of approach is you will at some point end up with primary key violations because of concurrency issues when more than 1 person is executing this code at the same time and they both get the same value. Either use an identity or if you are sql 2012+ you can use a sequence.

Comment: It will work properly only if you don't have a multiuser scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding parameter to the command but you haven't specified it in your command text at all.

```
SqlCommand getMaxCustID = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Customer_ID) FROM dbo.Customers",
                                  Form1.sqlConnection);
//getMaxCustID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", finalCustID); //Comment that out
```

Since you are not using your parameter `@custID`, you don't need to pass that to your command. Just comment that out or remove that line.

Later you are using the parameter `@custID` in yoru insert statement you need to add the parameter to that command object.

```
saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", finalCustID);
```

*(Thanks to @N55PEC)*, You are missing a comma between in your INSERT Command Text between your parameter and next value. It should be like:

NOTE: Additional formatting is used to keep the answer within the viewport.

```
SqlCommand saveRecord = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Customers " +
       "(Customer_ID,First_Name, Last_Name, Customer_Address,City,St,Zip,Phone,Email)" + 
       " Values (@custID,'firstName','lastName','address1','city','state'," +
       "'zip1','phoneNum','emailadd')", Form1.sqlConnection);
```

Comment: There is also an error in his second query (the insert one)

Comment: @N55PEC, yup just saw it, I was modifying my answer for that.

Comment: And in the saverecord there is also a comma missing after the "@custid": "@custID'firstName'" should be "@custID,'firstName'"  :)

Answer (score 0):

The command that requires the @custID parameter is called `saveRecord`, you add it to the command called  `getMaxCustID`

```
SqlCommand getMaxCustID = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Customer_ID) FROM dbo.Customers", Form1.sqlConnection);
Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(getMaxCustID.ExecuteScalar());
finalCustID = (int)count + 1;

SqlCommand saveRecord = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Customers (Customer_ID,First_Name, Last_Name, Customer_Address,City,St,Zip,Phone,Email)" + "Values (@custID', firstName','lastName','address1','city','state','zip1','phoneNum','emailadd')", Form1.sqlConnection);
saveRecord.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", finalCustID);
```

However, as I have said in the comment above, using MAX to retrieve the next number to assign to your next customer is clearly wrong in a multiuser environment. What if, another user add a customer while your code is between the execution of reading the customer id and inserting the new record? You will end with a Primary Key violation exception.

The best way to work with this scenario is to have the `Customer_ID` column as an [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column then write code like this

```
SqlCommand saveRecord = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO dbo.Customers 
       (First_Name, Last_Name, Customer_Address,City,St,Zip,Phone,Email)
        Values (@custID,'firstName','lastName','address1','city','state','zip1',
       'phoneNum','emailadd');
       SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", Form1.sqlConnection);
int newCustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(saveRecord.ExecuteScalar());
```

Notice, if you have Customer_ID as an IDENTITY column you should not try to pass a value for it, but you can retrieve the value assigned by the database engine using `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Answer (score 0):

Use Following line as it is:

```
SqlCommand getMaxCustID = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Customer_ID) FROM dbo.Customers", Form1.sqlConnection);
Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(getMaxCustID.ExecuteScalar());
```

Do:

```
int finalCustID = (int)count + 1;
```

And then:

```
SqlCommand saveRecord = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Customers (Customer_ID,First_Name, Last_Name, Customer_Address,City,St,Zip,Phone,Email)" + "Values ('finalCustID.toString() ','firstName','lastName','address1','city','state','zip1','phoneNum','emailadd')", Form1.sqlConnection);
```

And finally:

```
saveRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();
```